# Thesis won't compile after editing .bib

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, classicthesis

I'm writing my thesis using the Classic Thesis template.

My file compiled well until I added some references to my .bib file. Now TeXworks won't compile my thesis anymore, giving me the following.

Would anyone have any idea what has happened? I've spent the first four months of my thesis writing troubleshooting LaTeX, and would really like to get on with the actual writing...

Cheers.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ClassicThesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrreprt.cls
Document Class: scrreprt 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (report)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (./classicthesis-config.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin9.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrhack.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mparhack/mparhack.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acronym/acronym.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/suffix.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/listings.hak)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang2.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang3.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang2.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang3.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang2.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang3.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(./classicthesis.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/beramono.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eulervm/eulervm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrpage2.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocloft/tocloft.sty)
Using KOMA-command "deffootnote" for footnote setup
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrtime.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/prelim2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/remreset.sty)
\citation{*}
)) (./ClassicThesis.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pplj.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./ClassicThesis.out) (./ClassicThesis.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ppl.cfg)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (./FrontBackmatter/Titlepage.tex
<gfx/aalto_logo.png, id=4, 240.9pt x 200.75pt> <use gfx/aalto_logo.png>
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/t1fvm.fd) [1{/usr/local/texl
ive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./gfx/aalto_logo.png>])
[2] (./FrontBackmatter/Abstract.tex
Overfull \hbox (5.1162pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 15--16
\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 Logistics, Busi-ness De-vel-op-ment, fill-level sen-sor, Mac
hine-to-machine,
) [3] [4] (./FrontBackmatter/Contents.tex

Package hyperref Warning: old toc file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eulervm/uzeur.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-eur.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eulervm/uzeus.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-eus.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eulervm/uzeuex.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1zplm.fd) [5]

Package hyperref Warning: old lof file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.


Package hyperref Warning: old lot file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.


Package hyperref Warning: old lol file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd) [6]) [7] [8]
(./Chapters/Chapter01.tex
Chapter 1.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ts1pplj.fd) [9] [10])
[11] (./Chapters/Chapter02.tex [12]
Chapter 2.

Package natbib Warning: Citation `tkeskus_ruraldef' on page 13 undefined on inp
ut line 9.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `maaseudun_kehohj' on page 13 undefined on inp
ut line 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `maaseudun_kehohj' on page 13 undefined on inp
ut line 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `maaseudun_kehohj' on page 13 undefined on inp
ut line 24.

) [13] [14]
No file Chapters/Chapter03.tex.
[15] [16] (./Chapters/Chapter04.tex
Chapter 3.
) [17] (./Chapters/Chapter05.tex [18]
Chapter 4.

Overfull \hbox (63.50275pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--34
[]\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 Esimerkkitoimittajia - Agri-mar-ket - K-Maatalous - Pee�\T
S1/pplj/m/n/10.95 �\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 ss�\TS1/pplj/m/n/10.95 � \T1/pplj/m/n/10.
95 - L�\TS1/pplj/m/n/10.95 �\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 mp�\TS1/pplj/m/n/10.95 �\T1/pplj
/m/n/10.95 puisto

Overfull \hbox (30.21194pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 39--41
\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 ``Energiantuotannon kaksi jo-htavaa trendi�\TS1/pplj/m/n/10.
95 �\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 '' - Matti Pentti, L�\TS1/pplj/m/n/10.95 �\T1/pplj/m/n/1
0.95 mm�\TS1/pplj/m/n/10.95 �\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 ll�\TS1/pplj/m/n/10.95 �
) [19] (./Chapters/Chapter06.tex [20]
Chapter 5.

Overfull \hbox (10.63615pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10
[]\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 http://www.solinst.com/products/dataloggers-and-telemetry/
3001-

Overfull \hbox (0.2849pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10
\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 levelogger-series/technical-bulletins/understanding-pressure
-sensor-
) [21] (./Chapters/Chapter07.tex [22]
Chapter 6.
) [23] (./Chapters/Chapter08.tex [24]
Chapter 7.
) [25] [26] [27] [28] (./Chapters/Chapter09.tex
Chapter 8.
) [29] (./Chapters/Chapter10.tex [30]
Chapter 9.
) [31] (./Chapters/Chapter11.tex [32]
Chapter 10.

Overfull \hbox (0.84937pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
[]\chapterNumber 10 
) [33] (./Chapters/Chapter12.tex [34]
Chapter 11.

Overfull \hbox (0.84937pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
[]\chapterNumber 11 
) [35] [36] [37] [38] (./Chapters/Chapter13.tex
Chapter 12.

Overfull \hbox (0.84937pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
[]\chapterNumber 12 
) [39] (./Chapters/Chapter14.tex [40]
Chapter 13.

Overfull \hbox (0.84937pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
[]\chapterNumber 13 
) [41] (./Chapters/Chapter15.tex [42]
Chapter 14.

Overfull \hbox (0.84937pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
[]\chapterNumber 14 
) [43] [44] [45] [46] (./Chapters/Chapter16.tex
Chapter 15.

Overfull \hbox (0.84937pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
[]\chapterNumber 15 
) [47] [48] [49] [50] (./Chapters/Chapter0A.tex
Appendix A.
) [51] [52] (./FrontBackmatter/Bibliography.tex (./ClassicThesis.bbl
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> The Handbook of Logistics &
Distribution Management
l.14 ...ok of Logistics & Distribution Management}
.
? 

*
```

Comment: It seems that you have `The Handbook of Logistics & Distribution Management` in a title, instead of `Logistics \& Distribution`. Fix the `.bib` file, rerun BibTeX and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue comes from the "&" in "Logistics & Distribution Management". When parsing it, latex thinks it is alignment tab caracter (as stated in your log). You can try to replace "&" by "\&" (or "and" :) ).

Comment: Cheers guys, that helped. It seems I got confused by the massive amount of compilation errors, even if the problem was simple.